# Can I split larger Heartgard chewables for my smaller dog?

Tags: dogs, medicines

I have a 35 lb (16 kg) dog who normally takes [Heartgard chewables](https://heartgard.com/) for dogs sized 26 to 50 lbs (12 to 23 kg). Recently, my larger dog passed away, so I have some extras of the larger Heartgard chewables he used to take, for dogs sized 51 to 100 lbs (23 to 45 kg).

**Can I give these larger chewables to my smaller dog? Should I split them in half?**

Comment: Been splitting them for years, our dogs are only 5 and 9 lb . They passed the heartworm blood tests several times while using split doses of the med. Although I can't say they were exposed to mosquitoes carrying heart worm. I would split your pills ,maybe even into thirds: I think I have split some into thirds,

Answer (score 1):

You can probably split treats on the short term so as to not waste your remaining doses, but you should not rely on this methodology for the long term.  Per [the Heartgard prescription information](https://heartgardclinic.com/sites/default/files/2022-12/2022-hgd-plus-pi-rsg2.pdf), a single Heartgard chewable is designed to be a single dose and should be consumed entirely to achieve the appropriate dosage.

There is no evidence the micrograms of medication are evenly distributed throughout the treat.  Consuming half a treat does not guarantee half a dose has been administered to the pet.